# Calculo bicaudal em Java

Tags: java, matemática

Como posso fazer o cálculo bicaudal ou unicaudal em Java?

Este calculo é feito no Excel pela função `INVT`.

Esta função do Excel é feita da seguinte forma por exemplo: `=INVT(0,0455; 4,81E+01)` que retorna o valor `2,053`. Qual foi o cálculo que ela usou pra me retornar o valor `2,053`?

Não encontrei em lugar nenhum. Aí, gostaria de saber se alguém já usou alguma lib em java para calcular esta função do excel.

Comment: Francisco, por favor, edite sua pergunta e tente explicar o que você quer fazer com este cálculo.

Comment: O que é um cálculo bicaudal?

Comment: Não sei se existe uma função em java específica para isso, mas pelo que eu li ela utiliza um teste t de Student. Achei uma descrição da história do método e da fórmula utilizada pelo mesmo no link abaixo. Você pode utilizar o exemplo para implementar sua própria fórmula em java:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_t_de_Student

Comment: Acho que consigo fazer usando distribuição normal ao invés da distribuição t de Student. Qual é o seu interesse em particular com os graus de liberdade (o segundo parâmetro de `INVT`)?

Answer (score 0):

O framework Java que você precisa é esse no link abaixo:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/distribution.html

Melhor que implementar na mão.

O código vai ficar parecido com isso:

```
   TDistribution  t = new TDistribution(4.81E+1);
   double num = 1.0 - t.inverseCumulativeProbability(0.0455);
   System.err.println(num);
```

Leia a documentação que você vai entender e conseguir implementar certinho. Precisei na faculdade e o framework  me ajudou.

referência para resposta:

https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/INVT-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-INVT-a7c85b9d-90f5-41fe-9ca5-1cd2f3e1ed7c

http://www.epi.uff.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Tabela-T.pdf

Espero ter ajudado.